# Change CV layout

Tags: templates, moderncv

I'm a beginner.

I tried to write my CV in LaTeX and I downloaded the template from LaTeX Templates.

I used the `\cvitem` command but I got a problem. The margin seems too short to show all worlds in one line.

It should like this (This picture is from website):

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Should I change the `moderncv` template?

This is my code.

```
\cvitem{Date of Birth}{}
\cvitem{Place of Birth}{}
\cvitem{Gender}{Male}
\cvitem{Military Service}{}
\cvitem{Marital Status}{}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Can you please [post a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I tried using the code that you provided, but the output that I got was picture 1, not picture 2, so I was not able to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured out the issue. In the preamble of your document, you can add `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm}`. This will change the width of the column that contains the first entry of the `\cventry` command. Setting it to 3.5cm should give you something like picture 1, but you can of course adjust it as needed.